# restructuring pandas dataframe into meshgrid for basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to follow the [basemap tutorial for SST and ice analysis](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html). My input data is different from the data in the example though which comes from `netCDF4` as a masked array.

I have a `pandas` dataframe like:

```
val_df[0:5]
Out[47]:
    lat lon     value
0   0.4 98.7    NaN
1   0.4 98.8    NaN
2   0.4 98.9    0.64
3   0.4 99.0    NaN
4   0.5 98.5    1.23
```

The lats and lons represent a unique location on a map grid for the data point. To create a sample dataframe you can use the following code:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

locations = np.array([x for x in product([1,2,3],[4,5,6])])
data = np.random.random(len(locations))
val_df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':locations[:,0], 'lon':locations[:,1],
                      'value':data})
```

What I have done before is take this dataframe, pivot it (using the built-in pivot function) so that the `lat` column is the index and the `lon` column is the columns and the values are the values. Then I can use `m.imshow` to plot the resulting values.

However this seems to be a poor solution. A) `pcolormesh` is more recommended than`imshow` for reasons unclear to me, B) It seems like people typically use meshgrid and then a masked array. However, I'm really unclear as to how to structure my data into the meshgrid and masked array based on the basemap examples since the data in the examples comes pre-shaped.

When I create the mesh_grid of the lats/lons I do the following:

```
latmin = np.floor(val_df.lat.min())
latmax = np.ceil(val_df.lat.max())
lonmin = np.floor(val_df.lon.min())
lonmax = np.ceil(val_df.lon.max())
lats = np.arange(latmin, latmax, 0.1)
lons = np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, 0.1)
lats_mesh, lons_mesh = np.meshgrid(lats, lons)
```

But I am unclear at this point how to structure and mask the `value` column such that the values appear in the correct location of the mesh grid when I give it to `pcolormesh` like so:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
m = Basemap(projection='merc'
           , llcrnrlon=lonmin
           , llcrnrlat=latmin
           , urcrnrlon=lonmax
           , urcrnrlat=latmax)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()
m.fillcontinents(color='gray', lake_color='white', zorder=0)
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')

pc1 = m.pcolormesh(lons, lats, masked_data, shading='flat', cmap='hot_r', latlon=True)
```

Comment: Can you put an example with arbitrary data that we can run?

Comment: i added a deeper description.

Comment: If you want help it is important that you make a script that people can directly copy and run.

Comment: note the code that creates a sample dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the answer to my question is I needed to pivot my dataframe.

```
val_pivot_df = val_df.pivot(index='lat', columns='lon', values='b_value')
```

This pivots the dataframe, fills in the areas where there is no data with `NaNs` and returns it like so. Since basemap doesn't like pandas I then output the data as numpy arrays and plot it.

```
lons = val_pivot_df.columns.values
lats = val_pivot_df.index.values

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,8))

m = Basemap(projection='merc',
        llcrnrlat=val_df.dropna().min().lat-5
        , urcrnrlat=val_df.dropna().max().lat+5
        , llcrnrlon=val_df.dropna().min().lon-5
        , urcrnrlon=val_df.dropna().max().lon+5
        , resolution='i', area_thresh=10000
        )

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()
m.fillcontinents(color='gray', lake_color='white')#, zorder=0)
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='0.3')

x, y = np.meshgrid(lons,lats) 
px,py = m(x,y) 

data_values = val_pivot_df.values
masked_data = np.ma.masked_invalid(data_values)

cmap = plt.cm.viridis

m.pcolormesh(px, py, masked_data, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=2, shading='flat')

m.colorbar()
```